# Adding image in cakephp ajax link

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Iam using cakephp ajax link for calling a page

`<div id="post">
    </div>
    <?php echo $ajax->link(
    'View Post',
    array( 'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 1),
    array( 'update' => 'post', 'position' => 'top' )
    );
    ?>`

I want to display a image instead of the View Post . I have used `$html->imge` But it is not working
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<? echo $ajax->link($html->image('ragister-icon.png',array('title' => 'My Account','alt' => 'My Account','class' => 'lock-img')),array( 'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 1),array( 'update' => 'post', 'position' => 'top' ,'escape'=>false));?>
```

Comment: Dont forgot "'escape'=>false"